# Need to install PHP 5.6 into RHEL 8.3 with supporting sybase and oci8

Tags: php, oracle10g, sybase, php-5.6, rhel8

I have to install PHP 5.6 in RHEL 8.3
Must have sybase and oracle module as these are used for database connections.
What do I have to add to php installation to get these modules installed as well?

PHP 7 or above versions were not considered because doesnt support sybase module

Otherwise which version of php and rhel should i use to work with sybase ASE 15

Comment: Why are you installing outdated and unsupported software? PHP8.0.2 is available.

Comment: Because it is an already existing application trying to migrate to a aws